# call multiple methods simultaeously that returns returns object

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Calling multiple methods and i want to call them simultaneously that should wait for one another to get completed.

```
else {
    PricingFromS4Request pricingRequest = new PricingFromS4Request();
    ProductFromS4Request productRequest = new ProductFromS4Request();
    PricingFromS4ServiceImpl service = new PricingFromS4ServiceImpl();

    //Create 1 thread for below line
    pricingRequest = service.createS4PricingRequest(ABeanObject, SomeArrayList);

    //Create 1 more thread for below line
    productRequest = service.createS4ProductRequest(SomeList);

    //Send pricingRequest and productRequest  into another method 
    SomeMethod(pricingRequest,productRequest);

}
```

Unable to put the two lines inside the thread

Comment: Can you please format your code? I'm unclear about what you're asking. Which part of the code should be launched in a separate thread? Where it should wait for completion? What does "Unable to put the two lines inside the thread" mean?

Comment: You should be syncronizing all of your worker threads from your main thread and you should be using wait/notify methodology in that main thread as stated in this [document](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)

Comment: You can use `CompletableFuture` to do this kinda job.

Comment: Formated the code. Can you pls check now.

Comment: CompletableFuture runs on java 8 and my project runs on Java 7. Is there something else that can be done for Java 7?

Comment: You could use [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which uses java 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 7 this would an option:

```
    PricingFromS4Request pricingRequest = new PricingFromS4Request();
    ProductFromS4Request productRequest = new ProductFromS4Request();
    PricingFromS4ServiceImpl service = new PricingFromS4ServiceImpl();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Future<PricingFromS4Request> f1 = executor.submit(new Callable<PricingFromS4Request >() {
        public PricingFromS4Request  call() {
            return service.createS4PricingRequest(ABeanObject, SomeArrayList);
        }
    });
    Future<ProductFromS4Request> f2 = executor.submit(new Callable<ProductFromS4Request>() {
        public ProductFromS4Request call() {
            return service.createS4ProductRequest(SomeList);
        }
    });
    SomeMethod(f1.get(), f2.get());
    executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help Miguel. The above code works, but there is a doubt. Here, if f1() execution time is 5 seconds and if f2() completes in 50 seconds, does SomeMethod(f1.get(), f2.get()) execute without an issue ? if not how to make f1() wait for f2() to complete and then proceed with the next steps. As far as i checked f1() and f2() are not waiting for each other.

Comment: @arun It is guaranteed to execute. You see when you call "get" it will wait until the result is calculated, so SomeMethod will always wait for the other two to finish. If this solves your question please mark it as solved.

Comment: The solution works Miguel. the problem arises when i change data type to string.


    Future<String> f1 = executor.submit(new Callable<String >() {
            public String  call() {

 return dao.getS4PricingResponse(ABean);
            }
        });



The line   --->    dao.getS4PricingResponse returns and a string and im not able to assign it to some string variable. Why would that be ?

Comment: @arun You can always make another post with a complete explanation. I can not help with so little info,

Comment: Miguel can you pls help me on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523115/add-executors-dynamically-based-on-a-condition-in-java?noredirect=1#comment95849409_54523115